# Site antigo em primeiro na busca organica, se eu reforma-lo, perco rankeamento?

Tags: seo

Apareceu um site muito velho/feio aqui para mim reformar, e tenho de fazer um novo layout do zero e passa-lo para um CMS. 
Porém, ele esta em primeiro na busca orgânica do google. 
Vou perder rankeamento? Usarei o mesmo conteúdo.

Answer (score 3):

SEO envolve dezenas de recursos, como meta tags, .htaccess, sitemap, meta keywords etc. SEO trabalha diretamente com o conteudo dessas tags, e então você deve refazer o seu site o mais parecido possível, com as mesmas urls. Trabalhar com CMS vai dificultar ainda mais o processo, você deve ficar atento com a forma que esse CMS trata o SEO, verifique os plugins que ele disponibiliza, use as mesmas palavras chave em cada página. Gere o site-map novamente e atualize para o banco de dados do google. Gere o print da situação atual de seus links, e depois refaça seu site observando esses dados. Você vai cair no ranking com certeza, mas se fizeres um bom trabalho, com o tempo subirá novamente. Vai depender do momento, do igualdade de otimização entre os dois sites (Novo e Antigo). Não tenho dados para te passar, percentuais ou algo assim. Mas sabemos a concorrência e complexidade de trabalhar com SEO, e qualquer alteração com certeza acertará seu ranking.